# Android FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder error loading custom image

Tags: android, facebook

I'm debugging my application in a htc wildfire S and the below code is fine but when I try it with my samsung galaxy s4 mini appear a black window for a moment and close the activity that has to open the sharedialog. Samsung galaxy s4 mini has the last update and facebook app has updated too.

```
private void OpenShareDialog(){

    if (canPresentShareDialog) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null) {
            // Check for publish permissions
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

        }

        OpenGraphObject oplugar = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("namespace:lugar");
         oplugar.setProperty("og:type","namespace:lugar");
        oplugar.setProperty("og:title", LugarCargado.getNombre());
        //oplugar.setProperty("og:image", "http://estaticos.sport.es/resources/jpg/2/1/1391546433412.jpg");
        //oplugar.setProperty("og:url", "http://www.udg.edu/");
        oplugar.setProperty("og:description", LugarCargado.getDescripcion());



        Bitmap image=null;
        if (urifoto!=null){
            //image=ImagenAFacebook(urifoto);
            try {
                image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), urifoto);
                //images.add(bitmap);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }else{
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icoappfacebook2);
        }
        List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        bitmaps.add(image);

        //OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
        OpenGraphAction action = OpenGraphAction.Factory.createForPost("namespace:publicar");
        action.setProperty("lugar", oplugar);
        action.setType("namespace:publicar");
        //action.setProperty("previewPropertyName", "lugar");
        //action.setProperty("fb:explicitly_shared", true);
        //action.setExplicitlyShared(true);

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "lugar")
                //.setImageAttachmentsForObject("lugar", bitmaps, true)
                .setImageAttachmentsForAction(bitmaps, true)
                .build();

        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present()); 
    }else{
        publishFeedDialog();
    }
}
```

The difference is that SG4mini "LogCat - Skipped 86 frames! The application may be doing to much work on its main thread" and after 4 seconds black screen and seems that activity is closed and app restart from the previous activity.
And the other HTCWF seems that the image is loading and then sharedialog appears ok.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot.